# circular images?

Tags: php, image, geometry

I am making a site with PHP where users upload images for their profile. I already have that working just fine. However, I want the users images to be circles. From what I have read I believe that I can not crop an image into a circle, I will have to mask the image to make part of the image transparent. I have really no idea where to start. I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction, or maybe even some sample code!!!

Comment: Are you using gd or ImageMagick, or have you even gotten that far?

Comment: It's not the most cross-browser solution, but you could do it using CSS.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to actually edit the image if you have a consistent page background. Fake it out like so...

```
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-image: url('path/to/user/image.jpg'); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;" src="path/to/circle/mask.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

You could put quite a bit of this markup in your stylesheet too (to clean it up).

Answer (score 3):

Just save the image as a square, and use rounded corners to crop the image.

You will set the image to be a background image in a div, and set the CSS to have rounded corners (enough to make your div a circle). You can use PIE to make this CSS mark up work on IE 6-8 as well. See the PIE site for more details.

http://css3pie.com/about/

Comment: However here is how I get the users image. How do I put the users image into the background of the div??
<?php
$check_pic = "members/$id/image01.jpg";
$default_pic = "members/0/image01.jpg";
if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
    $user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic?$cacheBuster\" width=\"218px\" />"; 
} else {
    $user_pic = "<img src=\"$default_pic\" width=\"218px\" />"; 
}
?>

#apDiv20 { 
      //here's my only guess/attempt but it failed
 background-image: <?php $user_pic; ?>;  

 border-radius: 189px;
 position:absolute;
 width:378px;
 height:378px;
}

Comment: @user906357 you can probably do rounded corners on an image too. never tried.